# `OR` operator in the `CASE statement` between variables from the two different query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use the `OR` operator in the `CASE statement` between the two same name variables that are obtained from two different queries and display the final results.

Suppose I have the **First** query as:

```
  SELECT Id, CASE   
        WHEN [SUMTOTAL] >= 3  THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END AS [Engagement]
  FROM [Eng.[dbo].[VW_TotalMarks]
```

The Output from the first query is:

```
Id      |  Engagement
---------------------
478     |  0
2150    |  1
2173    |  1
2175    |  1
2182    |  1
2184    |  1
2209    |  0
```

And **Second Query** as:

```
  SELECT  Id, 
        WHEN [ACTIVITYTOTAL] >= 50  THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END AS [Engagement]
  FROM [Eng].[dbo].[View_ALLActivity] as ALN
```

The Output from the second query is:

```
Id      | Engagement
--------|------------
2175    |   0
2209    |   0
478     |   0
2173    |   1
2182    |   1
2150    |   1
2184    |   0
```

The expected output contains the results with the following case condition:

```
CASE WHEN ([dbo].[VW_TotalMarks].[Engagement] = 1 OR [EngagementDb_new].[dbo].[View_ALLActivity].[Engagement]=1) THEN 1
ELSE 0 END)
```

and the expected result will be:

```
Id      | Engagement
--------|------------
2175    |   1
2209    |   0
478     |   0
2173    |   1
2182    |   1
2150    |   1
2184    |   1
```

One option would be to Join two different views and use the case statement between two different results,
but is there any option to use the CASE directly with the query by not using any view?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated the result and sample data.

Comment: It makes no difference. Do what you find easy now, and others will find easy to understand wehn debugging the code in 5 years.

Comment: @jarlh sorry! what else do I need to upload?

Comment: You can repeat the code from the views, and then condense to simplify and avoid repeated trips into the same underlying tables. But to help with that, we need to see the SQL for the views.

Comment: Both the views already have very large join and they are big already so I extracted only one columns.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean not adding views for the queries you list that already use views.  Nesting views is something I don't like because it can hide issues.  You can use derived tables or a CTE to avoid adding new views.  (Assuming Id is a PK for simplicity.  Also, being quick and perhaps sloppy.)

```
SELECT COALESCE(q1.Id, q2.Id) as [Id], 
    CASE WHEN q1.Engagement = 1 OR q2.Engagement = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 as [Engagement]
FROM (
   Q1
) q1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
   Q2
) q2
ON q2.Id = q1.Id
```

IF you have a query that gives you the Id values desired, 2 left joins would also work.  This would avoid the need for the coalesce.